# How to get the index of a string in an array?

Tags: go

Here is my sample code:

```
slice_of_string := strings.Split("root/alpha/belta", "/")
res1 := bytes.IndexAny(slice_of_string , "alpha")
```

I got this error

```
./prog.go:16:24: cannot use a (type []string) as type []byte in argument to bytes.IndexAny
```

The logic here is when I input a path and a folder name (or file name), I want to know the level of the folder name (or a file name) in that path.

I do it by:

1. Split the path to an array
2. Get the index of the folder name (or a file name) in the path

If the index is 0 then the level would be 1, etc.

Comment: Write a for loop and compare. The logic or broken, however. It will fail for a path like `/a/a/a/a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to loop over the slice and find the element that you are looking for.

```
func main() {
    path := "root/alpha/belta"
    key := "alpha"
    index := getIndexInPath(path, key)
    fmt.Println(index)
}

func getIndexInPath(path string, key string) int {
    parts := strings.Split(path, "/")
    if len(parts) > 0 {
        for i := len(parts) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            if parts[i] == key {
                return i
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Note that the loop is backwards to address the logic issue that Burak Serdar pointed out that it may fail on a path like `/a/a/a/a` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strings.IndexAny` instead of `bytes.IndexAny` if you want to operate on a `[]string`.

Answer (score 1):

there are no inbuild function available in standard library to search in slice of string, but if slice of string is sorted then you can use `sort.SearchStrings` to search. But in case of unsorted slice of string you have to implement it using for loop.